# Java to replace fields in HTML

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf, jsoup

using java I want to replace every `{}` in

```
<td width="66"><p>{}</p></td><td width="96">
          <p><u><a href="{}">{}</a></u></p></td><td width="111"><p>{}</p></td>
<td width="283"><p>{}</p></td><td width="215"><p>{}</p></td>
<td width="137"><p>{}</p></td><td width="92"><p>{}</p></td>
<td width="99"><p><em>{}</em></p></td><td width="109"><p>{}</p></td>
<td width="109"><p>{}</p></td>
```

with values in mty java app. I tried looking into using jsoup (https://jsoup.org/) and also ThymeLeaf but no luck on either? Then after replacing I want to email that html. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Replace with what? what is wrong with string replaceAll method?

Comment: My apologies, I'm going to replace the `{}` with string values from my app.

Comment: Do you want to replace all occurrences of `{}` with the same value ? If so use `replaceAll`. Otherwise, replace them one by one by using `indexOf("{")`  and `indexOf("}")`

Comment: No, it will be different values. I'll have to look up the indexOf("{") and indexOf("}") ands how to use it. would just iterate over the string looking for the brackets?

Comment: If you can zero-index the `{}`s, like `{0}`, `{1}`, etc. then you can use `java.text.MessageFormat.format(..)` for this. Is it possible for you to generate the HTML template text like that?

Comment: @Billy can you update a sample input and expected out in your question details

Comment: Also index value is just a number how will you decide what value to replace with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the values you want to replace in any collection and do this:

```
static final Pattern PLACE_HOLDER = Pattern.compile("\\{\\}");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<td width=\"66\"><p>{}</p></td><td width=\"96\">\n"
        + "<p><u><a href=\"{}\">{}</a></u></p></td><td width=\"111\"><p>{}</p></td>\n"
        + "<td width=\"283\"><p>{}</p></td><td width=\"215\"><p>{}</p></td>\n"
        + "<td width=\"137\"><p>{}</p></td><td width=\"92\"><p>{}</p></td>\n"
        + "<td width=\"99\"><p><em>{}</em></p></td><td width=\"109\"><p>{}</p></td>\n"
        + "<td width=\"109\"><p>{}</p></td>";

    List<String> replacements = List.of("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K");
    Iterator<String> iterator = replacements.iterator();
    String output = PLACE_HOLDER.matcher(input).replaceAll(matcher -> iterator.next());

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

output:

```
<td width="66"><p>A</p></td><td width="96">
<p><u><a href="B">C</a></u></p></td><td width="111"><p>D</p></td>
<td width="283"><p>E</p></td><td width="215"><p>F</p></td>
<td width="137"><p>G</p></td><td width="92"><p>H</p></td>
<td width="99"><p><em>I</em></p></td><td width="109"><p>J</p></td>
<td width="109"><p>K</p></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Jsoup by following

```
    public static void replaceHtml() {
        String HEADER = "<html><head></head><body><table><tbody><tr>";
        String TAILER = "</tr></tbody></table></body></html>";
        String data = HEADER + "<td width=\"66\"><p>{}</p></td><td width=\"96\">\n" +
            "          <p><u><a href=\"{}\">{}</a></u></p></td><td width=\"111\"><p>{}</p></td>\n" +
            "<td width=\"283\"><p>{}</p></td><td width=\"215\"><p>{}</p></td>\n" +
            "<td width=\"137\"><p>{}</p></td><td width=\"92\"><p>{}</p></td>\n" +
            "<td width=\"99\"><p><em>{}</em></p></td><td width=\"109\"><p>{}</p></td>\n" +
            "<td width=\"109\"><p>{}</p></td>" + TAILER;
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data);
        Element table = doc.select("table").get(0); //select the first table.
        Elements rows = table.select("tr");
        Elements d = rows.select("td"); //select the first table.
        for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++) {
            //replace according to your need
            d.get(i).text("mytext");
        }
        doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
        String replacedData = doc.toString();
        replacedData = replacedData.replaceAll(HEADER, "");
        replacedData = replacedData.replaceAll(TAILER, "");
        System.out.println(replacedData);
    }
```